# Problema al eliminar registros con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hola a todos se que esto es algo básico de PHP pero al tratar de eliminar un registro me dice que si se eliminó , pero al consultar la base de datos me está manteniendo el registro y no lo borra, no sé que problema será.

Con este código obtengo el id del proveedor:

```
<a href="eliminarempresas.php?id=<?php echo $mostrar_p['codproveedor'] ?>"
class="eliminar ml-1" ><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
```

Y con este lo borro:

```
<?php

require_once "conexion.php";

$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "DELETE FROM proveedor where proveedor = '$id'";
$data = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if ($data ) {
    echo'si';
}else {
    echo'no';
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿El filtro debe ser `proveedor = $id` o `codproveedor = $id`?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo no estás concatenando bien la variable `$id` en la query, debería ser así:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM proveedor where proveedor = '".$id."'";
```

En el caso de que proveedor seá un `string` sería así, si fuera un `entero`, sería sin las comillas simples.

Comment: Muchas gracias verifique y funciono perfectamente

Comment: Tengo un campo estatus el cual me remplaza la acción eliminar si es 1 esta activo 0 inactivo que correspondería a eliminado , me actualiza el estatus UPDATE proveedor  SET estatus = 0 where codproveedor = '$id' pero no se elimina de la tabla en la parte visual (vista)